# nvd3 angular line update order

Tags: angular, nvd3.js

I am having trouble with nvd3 drawing lines backwards when I add data out of order.

I am trying to make a line chart with angular nvd3. My `X axis` is a date time value and my y axis is a number. I have set up data binding so that when new data is added to my scope object, the chart will be updated.
Sometime the data being added might be for a date before the existing data.

This causes the svg line to wrap back in on itself. Is there a way to make sure a line is always drawn from point to point in the order they are arranged on the axis, not the order they were added to the data set?

You can see an example of the kind of problem in this live updating nvd3 angular plunker. Here I make the `X` and `Y` both random and the line goes all over the place.

http://plnkr.co/edit/NDxrdZBfrg6Xn29GLuk0?p=preview

```
setInterval(function() {
  if (!$scope.run) return;
  $scope.data[0].values.push({
    x: Math.random() - 0.5,
    y: Math.random() - 0.5
  });
  if ($scope.data[0].values.length > 20) $scope.data[0].values.shift();
  x++;

  $scope.$apply(); // update both chart
}, 500);
```

[my app example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBRop.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer.

Sort the data before the updating the scope.
in this example something like:

```
// sort by value
$scope.data[0].values.sort(function (a, b) {
return a.x - b.x;
});
```

it would be more scalable to splice in the new data at the right place in the array in the first place and avoid sorting.